# Android Studio, "Cannot resolve the symbol myFragment1"

Tags: android, object

I am a creating a class in android "MyFragment1.java" but when I create its object "MyFragment1 myFragment1" and use it in 
"fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder,myFragment1);" 
then it shows me an error. Cannot resolve the symbol.
Any help on what I did  wrong?

Comment: You need to provide more details than this, Please post the error and the related code.

Answer (score 1):

1. package com.example.diveshpanwar.gossip;

   import android.app.Fragment; import android.app.FragmentManager;
   import android.app.FragmentTransaction; import
   android.content.DialogInterface; import
   android.os.PersistableBundle; import
   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout; import
   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; import
   android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; import android.os.Bundle; import
   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle; import
   android.view.Menu; import android.view.MenuInflater; import
   android.view.MenuItem; import android.view.View; import
   android.widget.AdapterView; import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.ListView;

   import java.lang.reflect.Array; import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class Home extends ActionBarActivity implements
   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

   ```
   private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
   private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
   private ListView navList;
   private android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
       drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
       navList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navlist);
       ArrayList<String> navArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        //-----------Holds Fragment values--------------//
       navArray.add("Switch Sections");
       navArray.add("Home");
       navArray.add("Select Colleges");
       navArray.add("Content creator");
       navArray.add("About");
       navArray.add("Help");

       //-------------------Displays Currently selected fragment-------------//
       navList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
       //---------------------------------------//

       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,navArray);
       navList.setAdapter(adapter);
       navList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
       actionBarDrawerToggle =new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.opendrawer,R.string.closedrawer);
       drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

      //--------------Manage Fragment Manager -----------------//
       android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


       //-------------Creates action bar--------------//
     ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

       //-----------Icon in action bar---------------//
      // actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
      // actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);

       //------------Display action bar-----------//
       actionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

       //------------loads fragment 0 by default i.e "Switch Sections"--------------//
       loadSelection(0);
   }
   ```

   //--------------------Menu inflaters---------
       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
           return true;
       }

   ```
   //-----------Function to perform action on fragment selected-----//
   private  void loadSelection(int i){

       navList.setItemChecked(i,true);
       if (i==1){

           MyFragment1 myFragment = new MyFragment1();
           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder,myFragment1);
           fragmentTransaction.commit();
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
       actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

       int id=item.getItemId();
       if(id==R.id.action_settings){
           return  true;
       } else  if(id == android.R.id.home){

           if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navList)){
               drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
           }
           else{
               drawerLayout.openDrawer(navList);
           }

       }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }


   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       switch (position) {
           case 0:

               break;
           case 1:
               loadSelection(position);
               break;
           case 2:

               break;
           case 3:

               break;
           case 4:

               break;
           case 5:

               break;

       }

       //--------------------close fragment list after an option is being clicked-----------//
       drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: error occurs in the definition of the user defined function loadSelection()

Comment: You should edit your questions with this information instead of posting an answer (as this is not an answer to the question)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, you seem to be missing the import for `MyFragment1`, at the beginning of the file next to the other imports, add something like this:

```
import <PATH to class>.MyFragment1;
```

Replace  with the real path to your fragment class